# Add to Favorite Function using Shared Preferences Android

Tags: android, sqlite, preferences, shared, favorite

I wanted to create an add favorite function for my item in a list view. But i have no idea which approach i should use, either shared preferences or sqlite DB.
Can any one give opinion regarding this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hold small data, like ID's or something, you should use `SharedPreferences` - they're fast and easy to use. Keep it as `String` with ex. comma as separator or just use `Set`.

If you want to hold big amount of structured, organized, data, keeping whole object, it would be better to use SQLite database. This is more complicated.

Remember both options are read/write operations, so they must not be done on main thread.

Comment: Thanks for the useful info provided.